# Delete all combinations from a number

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers to 000 at 300 and I would like to delete all the combinations, like 012,021, 120,210 and just keep the first number (012). I tried with the function permutation who gave me all the combinations of the list, but for example when I tried to delete 021, 120 and 210, it deleted 012 too.

```
from itertools import permutations
for i in range(0, 301):
    liste.append("{0:03}".format(i))

for i in liste:
    combi = permutations(i, 3)

    for j in combi:
        resultat = "".join(j)
    if resultat in liste:
        liste.remove(j)
```

Comment: When you say "combinations" do you mean "permutations"?

Comment: The code does not work. You did not declare "liste". Moreover you check if "resultat" is in list but if it is you remove j which is not the same

Answer (score 3):

This should work:
We are sorting each number in the list and using `set()` to remove the duplicates.

```
for i in range(0, 301):
    liste.append("{0:03}".format(i))
c = sorted(list(set([''.join(sorted(x)) for x in liste])))
```

Comment: This is the most straight-forward answer. It has the least overhead and efficiently uses the data structures of Python compared with the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from collections import Counter

def only_first_permutation(liste):
    passed_digit_sets = set()
    for n in liste:
        digits = frozenset(Counter(n).items())

        if digits in passed_digit_sets:
            continue

        passed_digit_sets.add(digits)
        yield n


liste = list(only_first_permutation("{0:03}".format(i) for i in range(301)))

print(liste)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, I would sort the digits and send them through a dict, such that only the first number with a certain combinations of digits is kept. This assumes that you are interested in the triples of digits, even with repetitions. The final list therefore still has both `100` and `110`. Reversing the input list makes sure that the smalles values for each digit combination are being kept.

```
liste = list(reversed(list(map("{0:03}".format, range(0, 301)))))
sorted_digits = [tuple(sorted(n)) for n in liste]
final_list = list(dict(list(zip(sorted_digits, liste))).values())

sorted(final_list)
#out:
['000',
 '001',
 '002',
 '003',
 '004',
 '005',
 '006',
 '007',
 '008',
 '009',
 '011',
 '012',
 '013',
 '014',
 '015',
 '016',
 '017',
 '018',
 '019',
 '022',
 '023',
...
```